# UIImage behind GLKView

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, uiimage, glkview

i'm trying to create a signature with touch inputs using a GLKView.
But now i need a UIImage to be below the signature.
Short: I want to draw lines above a UIImage using a custom GLKView.

The problem is that my line gets drawn below the image every time, no matter if i set opaque to NO and insertSubview: belowSubview..

Otherwise i tried with the help of textures but i have no idea how to do this..

I do not want to use a GLKViewController if it is possible ;)
Thanks in advance!

Update:

I found my problem and now i get the result that i wanted to have.

Inside the GLKView in the Constructor i initiate the EAGLContext.
I forgot to set the context to self.

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

if (context) {

    self.opaque = NO; // set view transparent
    self.context = context; // set the context to itself
}
```

Although setting opaque to NO is not a good solution it is the only efficient solution for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways worth looking at to do this.

One is to look at view containment instead of layering — make the `GLKView` a subview of the view you're drawing a `UIImage` in.

The other is to draw the image in your `GLKView` using OpenGL ES. It's a little more work, but not too hard if you look over the documentation and the answers already here on SO. And it has some extra benefits: since both the background image and your drawing are going into the same framebuffer, you can control blending in GL. Here's some tips for getting started:

1. Use [`GLKTextureLoader`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) to get your image into an OpenGL ES texture.
2. Set up a [`GLKBaseEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKBaseEffect_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010912) instance for drawing with your texture. Don't forget to tell it to `prepareToDraw`.
3. Draw a quad using the texture and effect. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13456126/957768) has a pretty decent starting point for doing that.
4. After drawing the background image, draw your signature and it'll be on top of the image.

Comment: First thank you for your answer, i would definitely try to focus on your first recommondation which is view containment.
But there are some problems:
- the draw method of the GLKView is not called
- if i force drawing via code it is still not visible
- taking a snapshot of the GLKView shows my Signature, which kind of confuses me
Im loading the 'parent' UIView is a nib file, and inserting view below supbview is also not helping ;)

Comment: How are you "forcing drawing"? To make a `GLKView` (or any `UIView` subclass) draw itself, you call its `setNeedsDisplay` method, which prepares it for drawing and in turn calls your `drawRect:` or `glkView:drawInRect:` method.

Comment: The snapshot method of GLKView "forced" the drawing. But i already found my problem which I will edit in my answer. A part of the problem was my own stupidness ;) example: i turned off enableSetNeedsDisplay.